# Mysql Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value in INSERT query

Tags: mysql, insert, warnings, mysql-error-1292

I know there are lots of bugs like this around here but this query seems to be different, as it's an insert query. Here is the schema for the table card_info:

```
CREATE TABLE card_info (
 card_id mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 card_name_orig varchar(150) NOT NULL,
 card_name_html varchar(150) NOT NULL,
 card_name_search varchar(150) NOT NULL,
 card_name_page varchar(150) NOT NULL,
 card_cost varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 card_cost_converted tinyint(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 card_subtype varchar(75) DEFAULT NULL,
 card_oracle_text_orig text,
 card_oracle_text_html text,
 card_power varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
 card_toughness varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
 card_loyalty tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (card_id),
 KEY card_name_nd (card_name_search),
 KEY card_name_page (card_name_page),
 KEY card_cost_converted (card_cost_converted),
 KEY card_power (card_power),
 KEY card_toughness (card_toughness),
 KEY card_loyalty (card_loyalty),
 FULLTEXT KEY card_oracle_text_orig (card_oracle_text_orig),
 FULLTEXT KEY card_name_search (card_name_search)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

And here is my query:

```
INSERT INTO card_info (
 card_name_orig, card_name_html, card_name_search, card_name_page, card_cost,
 card_cost_converted, card_subtype, card_oracle_text_orig, card_oracle_text_html,
 card_power, card_toughness, card_loyalty
)
SELECT DISTINCT
 d.name_orig, d.name_html, d.name_search, d.name_page, d.cost,
 COALESCE(d.cost_converted, 0),   d.type_sub, d.oracle_text_orig,
 d.oracle_text_html, d.`power`, d.toughness, d.loyalty
FROM card_info_de d
LEFT OUTER JOIN card_info i ON d.name_search = i.card_name_search
WHERE i.card_id IS NULL
AND d.edition_id = 'isd'
ORDER BY (d.collector_number + 0), d.collector_number;
```

If I perform this query, I'm getting this error:

## 1292 - Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '181a'

Please note that the value **181a** is from the column **`card_info_de`.`collector_number`** and it is a **VARCHAR(5)** field, and that field isn't being inserted to the **`card_info`** table anyway, it's just being used in the order clause of the select query.

If I do the query starting from the `SELECT` only, I can see the correct results are being selected, but when I do the insert, it gives me the error above. Do note that If I remove the ORDER BY clause from the SELECT query, it inserts fine. I don't have a clue what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you share the schema for table card_info

Comment: I updated the question with the schema. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 6):

Just hit the same error myself and it is a bit misleading. I found the answer in another thread:

[Error Code 1292 - Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value - Mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16069446/6717225)

> This message means you're trying to compare a number and a string in a `WHERE` or `ON` clause. Either make sure they have similar declarations, or use an explicit `CAST` to convert the number to a string.
>
> If you turn off `strict` mode, the error should turn into a warning.
>
> [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar)

So basically check for any of these columns being treated as the wrong data type:

`d.name_search`
`i.card_name_search`
`d.edition_id`
`d.collector_number`

Answer (score 0):

Try

ORDER BY (d.collector_number + '0'), d.collector_number;

Terrible if true, but quite possible.

Comment: Since the two values of collector_number are "181b" and "181a", and let's say there's a third record which has "180", I want them inserted in a way where my first sort is only the numbers ascending "(d.collector_number + 0) ASC", and next is sort the letters "d.collector_number ASC". I'm sorry but I need the ordering that way.

Comment: I didn't change the order. 180 + '0' is '1800' and will be before '180a'. All I did was tell the sql that '0' was a string not a number, seeing as the order by clause is the problem and you've told it to add 0 to a string, and your string is 180a which is not a number....

Comment: You can put ASC back in if you want, but it's the default. Looking at what you've done I can see why you might want them in that order, I'd have added collector number to the card table though.