# Error Code 1292 - Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value - Mysql

Tags: mysql, truncated, mysql-error-1292

I am not sure what is this error!

```
#1292 - Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value:
```

I don't have double value field or data!

I have wasted a whole hour trying to figure this out!

here is my query

```
INSERT INTO call_managment_system.contact_numbers 
    (account_id, contact_number, contact_extension, main_number, created_by)
SELECT
    ac.account_id,
    REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(ta.phone_number, '-', ''), ' ', ''), ')', ''),'(','') AS Phone,
    IFNULL(ta.ext, '') AS extention,
    '1' AS MainNumber,
    '2' AS created_by
FROM 
    cvsnumbers AS ta
    INNER JOIN accounts AS ac ON ac.company_code = ta.company_code
WHERE 
    LENGTH(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(ta.phone_number, '-', ''), ' ', ''), ')', ''),'(','') ) = 10
```

here is my show create table for the table which the results are going into

```
CREATE TABLE `contact_numbers` (  
    `number_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
    `account_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',  
    `person_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',  
    `contact_number` char(15) NOT NULL,  
    `contact_extension` char(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',  
    `contact_type` enum('Primary','Direct','Cell','Fax','Home','Reception','Office','TollFree') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Primary',  
    `contact_link` enum('Account','PDM','Other') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Account',  
    `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT '0 = inactive, 1=active', 
    `main_number` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '1 = main phone number',  
    `created_on` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,  
    `created_by` int(11) NOT NULL,  
    `modified_on` datetime DEFAULT NULL,  
    `modified_by` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',  
    PRIMARY KEY (`number_id`),  
    KEY `account_id` (`account_id`),  
    KEY `person_id` (`person_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=534 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: According to [this bug report](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=63112) the message comes from comparing a string column with an integer, because they both get converted to `double` for the comparison. How are `ac.company_code` and `ta.company_code` declared?

Comment: See also http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=46641 where a poster suggested that this error message be reworded to "WHERE comparisons between numerical and non-numerical columns are not allowed"

Comment: Both of those columns are int(11) and not strings!

Comment: Can you make a sqlfiddle with some sample data?

Answer (score 226, accepted):

This message means you're trying to compare a number and a string in a `WHERE` or `ON` clause. In your query, the only potential place where that could be occurring is `ON ac.company_code = ta.company_code`; either make sure they have similar declarations, or use an explicit `CAST` to convert the number to a string.

If you turn off `strict` mode, the error should turn into a warning.

Comment: Wow, what a misleading error message. Thanks for helping. You were right. I needed to change `DB::table('contacts')->where('attendance', $int)
                    ->update(["attendance" => $string]);` to `DB::table('contacts')->where('attendance', '' . $int)
                    ->update(["attendance" => $string]);`

Comment: Thanks for this. To expand: there are all sorts of ways in which this can be triggered. In my case, it was using a regexp to extract an integer from a string, and comparing this against an integer. Weirdly, when I just used the SELECT statement, it was all fine:
select xxxx from t1 inner join t2 on t1.id=substr(value,locate(':',tagvalue)+1)
Once I turned that into an INSERT...SELECT, the error was triggered.

Comment: I encountered this issues when using `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE pk1=pk1 AND pk2=pk2`. Replacing `AND` with `,` fixed my issue. Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456258/mysql-truncated-incorrect-double-value

Comment: Convert Where clause values to string, did the job thanks

Comment: Thanks.  Turns out I was sending a color as a string rather than as an integer.  Worked for years, new server and it started barking.  No doubles in sight!

Comment: @LorenPechtel You probably upgraded the MySQL version, which changed the default SQL_MODE.

Comment: @Barmar Probably, but I had nothing to do with the server, I just had to hunt the error.

Answer (score 39):

I corrected this error as there was a syntax error or some unwanted characters in the query, but MySQL was not able to catch it. I was using `and` in between multiple fields during update, e.g.

```
update user 
set token='lamblala', 
    accessverion='dummy' and 
    key='somekey' 
where user = 'myself'
```

The problem in above query can be resolved by replacing `and` with comma(`,`)

Comment: Thanks this is not a big issue but sometime small problem becomes big issue

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! This happened to me in the context of an update statement

Answer (score 15):

I was facing the same issue. Trying to compare a varchar(100) column with numeric 1. Resulted in the 1292 error. Fixed by adding single quotes around 1 ('1').

Thanks for the explanation above

Answer (score 6):

**TL; DR**

This might also be caused by applying `OR` to string columns / literals.

**Full version**

I got the same error message for a simple `INSERT` statement involving a view:

```
insert into t1 select * from v1
```

although all the source and target columns were of type `VARCHAR`. After some debugging, I found the root cause; the view contained this fragment:

```
string_col1 OR '_' OR string_col2 OR '_' OR string_col3
```

which presumably was the result of an automatic conversion of the following snippet from Oracle:

```
string_col1 || '_' || string_col2 || '_' || string_col3
```

(`||` is string concatenation in Oracle). The solution was to use

```
concat(string_col1, '_', string_col2, '_', string_col3)
```

instead.

Comment: Thank-you! New to MySQL, I was concatenating using the SQL Server allowed way, something like string1 + string2 + string3. Your suggestion of the concat function fixed this error for me.

Answer (score 4):

I've seen a couple cases where this error occurs:

### 1. using the not equals operator `!=` in a `where` clause with a list of multiple `or` values

such as:

```
where columnName !=('A'||'B')
```

This can be resolved by using

```
where columnName not in ('A','B')
```

### 2. missing a comparison operator in an `if()` function:

```
select if(col1,col1,col2);
```

in order to select the value in `col1` if it exists and otherwise show the value in `col2`...this throws the error; it can be resolved by using:

```
select if(col1!='',col1,col2);
```

Answer (score 1):

When I received this error I believe it was a bug, however you should keep in mind that if you do a separate query with a SELECT statement and the same WHERE clause, then you can grab the primary ID's from that SELECT: `SELECT CONCAT(primary_id, ',')`) statement and insert them into the failed UPDATE query with conditions -> "WHERE [primary_id] IN ([list of comma-separated primary ID's from the SELECT statement)" which allows you to alleviate any issues being caused by the original (failed) query's WHERE clause.

For me, personally, when I was using quotes for the values in the "WHERE ____ IN ([values here])", only 10 of the 300 expected entries were being affected which, in my opinion, seems like a bug.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have double value field or data, maybe you should try to disable sql strict mode.

To do that you have to edit "**my.ini**" file located in MySQL installation folder, find "Set the SQL mode to strict" line and change the below line:

```
# Set the SQL mode to strict
sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

to this, deleting "STRICT_TRANS_TABLES"

```
# Set the SQL mode to strict
sql-mode="NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

After that, you have to **restart MySQL service** to enable this change.

To check the change, open the editor an execute this sql sentence:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_mode';
```

**Very Important**: Be careful of the file format after saving. Save it as "UTF8" and don't as "TFT8 with BOM" because the service will not restart.

Comment: It's more safe to do this per session basis, or even better only in the specific script that's modifying the 'troublesome tables': `$pdo->query('SET SESSION SQL_MODE = "ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"')` and after your script magic, turn strict back on same way:`$pdo->query('SET SESSION SQL_MODE = "STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"')`

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a view (highly nested, view in view) insertion causing the error in [mysql-5.6](/questions/tagged/mysql-5.6):

```
CREATE TABLE tablename AS
  SELECT * FROM highly_nested_viewname
;
```

The workaround we ended up doing was simulating a materialized view (which is really a table) and periodically insert/update it using stored procedures.

Answer (score 0):

Had this issue with ES6 and TypeORM while trying to pass `.where("order.id IN (:orders)", { orders })`, where `orders` was a comma separated string of numbers. When I converted to a template literal, the problem was resolved.

```
.where(`order.id IN (${orders})`);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have used **CHECK CONSTRAINT** on table for string field length

e.g: to check username length >= 8

use:

```
CHECK (CHAR_LENGTH(username)>=8)
```

instead of

```
CHECK (username>=8)
```

fix the check constraint if any have wrong datatype comparison