# Select X as Y query with Where, Having AND ORDER BY Y gives 1292 warning but fine without ORDER BY

Tags: mysql

I use the Haversine query to calculate the distance to property. But even though it works, I did notice I get Warning 1292 messages in PhpMyAdmin and HeidiSQL. I'd like to get rid of those but my search has come to an end.

The query looks like this and as said, works fine but with Warnings:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.garage, t1.more_info_url, t1.date_b, t1.mak_id, t2.id AS m_id, t1.is_b, t1.price, t1.lat, t1.lng, 
(6371 * ACOS(COS(RADIANS('52.0791005')) * COS(RADIANS(t1.lat)) * COS(RADIANS(t1.lng) - RADIANS('4.2666311')) + SIN(RADIANS('52.0791005')) * SIN(RADIANS(t1.lat)))) AS distance
FROM alert t1
LEFT JOIN users t2 ON t2.id = t1.mak_id
WHERE is_b = 'on' 
AND (date_b BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL '180' DAY AND CURDATE()) 
AND (t1.price > 180000) 
AND (t1.price < 840000)
HAVING DISTANCE < '140'
ORDER BY distance ASC
```

This results in this error multiple times:

```
Warning: #1292 Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: ''
```

However, when I remove the last line, the ORDER BY clause, all is fine. I have already tried to switch things around, had (single)quotes at every possible position, but I don't understand it anymore.

So, this runs without warnings:

```
 SELECT t1.id, t1.garage, t1.more_info_url, t1.date_b, t1.mak_id, t2.id AS m_id, t1.is_b, t1.price, t1.lat, t1.lng, 
    (6371 * ACOS(COS(RADIANS('52.0791005')) * COS(RADIANS(t1.lat)) * COS(RADIANS(t1.lng) - RADIANS('4.2666311')) + SIN(RADIANS('52.0791005')) * SIN(RADIANS(t1.lat)))) AS distance
    FROM alert t1
    LEFT JOIN users t2 ON t2.id = t1.mak_id
    WHERE is_b = 'on' 
    AND (date_b BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL '180' DAY AND CURDATE()) 
    AND (t1.price > 180000) 
    AND (t1.price < 840000)
    HAVING DISTANCE < '140'
```

Not sure if it is related, but the only DOUBLE field is "price" in t1. It holds the price of real estate property. I had that surrounded by single quotes in my tests as well. I'm afraifd I have tried all that I know.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you quote `140`? It's a number, it doesn't need to be quoted.

Comment: You have unnecessary quotes around lots of numbers. Why? I have a feeling this is related to the problem.

Comment: The quotes around the lat/lng are from the real_escape_string function, some of the others are there from testing. They did not influence the outcome.

Comment: You shouldn't be using `real_escape_string`, you should use prepared statements with `bind_param()`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. We do that on some other projects, not this one (it's another discussion as well I guess, I think prepared statements are longwinded :-)). Either way I don't think that is the problem here.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16068993/error-code-1292-truncated-incorrect-double-value-mysql This error happens when trying to compare a number and a string in strict mode. So it's probably related to quoting numbers.

Comment: I had read that and many other posts about it before asking myself. I did a lot of research, which is why I stated I did try with and without quotes as I go tthat from just about all I could find on Stack E. and Google. Thanks for your efforts though, really appreciate it.

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a sqlfiddle?

Comment: Never done that. I'll try to find a way

Comment: The site I like is db-fiddle.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to create a fiddle and got an error there (not on my own setups, only at the fiddle) about my date field:

`date_available` DATE NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',

So I took a closer look and tested more. Eventually the warnings were gone after putting the *date_available*, as well as the *distance* in single quotes in the ORDER BY clause.