# Having error on insert row ER_TRUNCATED_WRONG_VALUE: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'null'

Tags: mysql, node.js

Having error on NodeJs after successfully insert query executed.

The confusing thing is data inserted in the Table successfully and not getting an error inside the callback function `db.query(insertMsgQuery, (err, rows, fields) => { console.log('query error === ', err) });` but due to error shown below my Node APP crashed `[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...`

**Insert Query**

```
INSERT INTO `chat_thread_messages` (`thread_id`,`msg_text`,`from`,`to`,`product_id`,`msg_type`) VALUES (9,'Bonjour, Cet article est-il toujours disponible?',6,7,4,'text')
```

**Error**

```
node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:437
      throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
      ^

Error: ER_TRUNCATED_WRONG_VALUE: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'null'
```

**Schema**
[image]

Comment: Can you add the schema for `chat_thread_messages`? Are your values all cast properly and do you have any constraints in place?

Comment: I just updated my question with schema image see. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error Code 1292 - Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value - Mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16068993/error-code-1292-truncated-incorrect-double-value-mysql)