# How to solve this error ?I have to add data to existing data

Tags: mysql

here is my sql query :

```
update users set text=text +'submit Assignment'  where day='Day3';
```

When I run it, I get the error:

```
Error Code: 1292. Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'submit Assignment' 0.000 sec.
```

i got it, for string we have to use concat(text,?) instead of '+'

Comment: Please share more details, and your debugging attempts

Comment: This will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16068993/error-code-1292-truncated-incorrect-double-value-mysql/16069446#:~:text=This%20message%20means%20you're,a%20WHERE%20or%20ON%20clause.&text=company_code%20%3B%20either%20make%20sure%20they,should%20turn%20into%20a%20warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
update users set text=concat(text,'submit Assignment') where day='Day3'
```