# MariaDB UPDATE query only successful using ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, mariadb, sql-update

Folks,

I got an error in a simple update query:
SQL Error (1292): Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value

The SELECT query gives 4000 results:

```
SELECT * 
FROM items
WHERE item_id IN (<<list of idies>>) AND item_status = 7;
```

The UPDATE query returns the error:

```
UPDATE items
SET item_status = 15
WHERE item_id IN (<<list of idies>>) AND item_status = 7;
```

**SQL Error (1292): Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: ''**

But I found out that when ORDER BY has been added to the UPDATE query, it runs perfectly without any errors:

```
UPDATE items
SET item_status = 15
WHERE item_id IN (<<list of idies>>) AND item_status = 7
ORDER BY item_id ASC
```

So, listing of all data is totally fine; but apparently with the update it's treating the data differently and gives an error. Anyone any ideas what this could be? I'm more a psql user.
It's working with this ugly solution, but I'm just curious how on earth this can happen, and what an ORDER BY can change of performing the UPDATE.

Table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE `items` (
 `item_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `subscription_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 `item_type` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
 `item_ref_id` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `item_status` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `item_name` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
 `item_mode` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL COMMENT 'BASE or OPTIONAL' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
 `item_interval` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
 `item_price` DECIMAL(10,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
 `item_qty` DOUBLE NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 `item_activatie` DECIMAL(10,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
 `item_deactivatie` DECIMAL(10,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
 `deactivatie_voldaan` ENUM('Y','N') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
 `item_startdate` DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
 `item_enddate` DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
 `date_invoiced` DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
 `round_period` VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'M' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
 `invoice_group_tag` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
 PRIMARY KEY (`item_id`) USING BTREE,
 INDEX `item_ref_id` (`subscription_id`) USING BTREE
)
```

No triggers or fancy stuff.

Tried to check for data integrity, COALESCE'd all NULL values, used INSERTS to rebuild the table; all fine.
I don't want to spent more time on digging in to it, just curious if anyone knows what it could be theoretically. The original WHERE query consists of more fields and some date range filtering, but returned a list of item_id's successfully;

NON blocking... ; don't spend too much time on it :)

Thanks!

Comment: Please add full error message and table definition (as text) AND check any triggers on the table..

Comment: Maybe like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16068993/error-code-1292-truncated-incorrect-double-value-mysql

Comment: This error message usually shows the value that's the problem.

Comment: The published create table has an error - Key column 'abonnement_id' doesn't exist in table

Comment: @Barmar Thanks! The error message itself is something I can understand; The strange thing is that it shows it only when I don't add a ORDER BY, it should never (or always) show the error.

Comment: Yes, that's strange, maybe a bug. Can you create an [mre] that reproduces this?

Comment: 20 years ago I said many times: "must be a bug!", but learned it was 99% my own fault. Learned to be cautious saying this now.. :) 
Probably when I create a minimal reproducible example, I'll find the issue; will do when I have a bit more time.
thnx!

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue https://dbfiddle.uk/ksImlUFR please add version to the question.

Comment: 0

Why are your default values for int(11) column's '0'. Shouldn't it be 0

Comment: Perhaps it is storing a big value from an expression into one of those _`DECIMALs`_?

Comment: Try adding `INDEX(status, item_id)`.

Comment: File a bug report -- the error message is _at least_ misleading.  What version of MariaDB or MySQL?  Is it a GA version?

Comment: Looks like a bug. ORDER BY should be ignored anyway. but it doesn't mean that you did nothing wrong :-) The only DOUBLE column is `item_qty`. Maybe you have corrupt data in the table. But don't ask me how a DOUBLE value can be corrupt/invalid. What you can do is to reduce the "(<<list of idies>>)" to a minimum set (ideally a single ID) that triggers the error.

Comment: Version: 10.3.34-MariaDB-0+deb10u1
Yes, the table structure (and defaults) is not great (I'm not the maintainer), still it makes no sense that it only updates with ORDER (probably some other tricks will work too)
I'm convinced it has something to do with one or more rows with corrupt data, but in all cases it is unexpected behaviour and I agree with the misleading error message.  Thnx

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I expect the same, probably corrupt data in a row (although I recreated the table with INSERTS to prevent this). The reason I found out that it worked with ORDER BY was that I tried to update a couple at a time so I could find any wrong rows; but ultimately the error disappeared because of this.